# Exponential of the sum of two non-commuting operators where their commutator is proportional to one of them

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, operators, commutator

I was shown the following property:

Given two operators $A$ and $B$, and $$[A,B]=-\frac{k}{2}B,$$ being $k$ an arbitrary constant, then:

$$ \exp(A+B)=\exp(A)\exp\left(\frac{-2}{k}B  \left(1-e^{\frac{-k}{2}}\right)\right)$$

Is this correct? I guess this result is derived from the BCH theorem, or even the Zassenhaus formula, but I don't think it's trivial to get there. Does anyone know where did this come from?

Comment: Have you tried to compute $[A,[A,B]]$...? That being said, please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). Please check all parentheses again, I hope I did not change the meaning of the equation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: If $$[A,B]~=~aB, \qquad a~\in~ \mathbb{C},$$ then one may show that the [BCH formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baker%E2%80%93Campbell%E2%80%93Hausdorff_formula) collapses [to](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baker%E2%80%93Campbell%E2%80%93Hausdorff_formula#Special_cases) $${\rm BCH}(A,B)~=~A+\frac{a}{1-e^{-a}}B$$
when the denominator is non-zero.

Comment: I see, i completely missed that property while reading about the BCH formula. Thanks for the answer and the editing.

Comment: see also [this recent arxiv article](https://arxiv.org/abs/2107.01204) by Dupays which deals with variations on this theme.